# How much RAM is there in an an iOS (Iphone/iPad/iPod Touch) Device?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, macos

Different iPhones have different published memory 4GB, 8GB and 16GB. The touch can have 32GB. My understanding is this is the off-line memory (disk alike).

How much actual fast ram is there in the device available for my Cocoa Application?

Is there a preconfigured virtual amount?

Comment: Make sure your app doesn't request for more than 40M bytes of memory or some of the early device users will suffer crash quite easily

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[image]Currently released Apple iOS devices have the following amounts of working memory:

```
iPhone        =  128 MB
iPhone 3G     =  128 MB
iPhone 3GS    =  256 MB
iPhone 4      =  512 MB
iPhone 4S     =  512 MB    
iPhone 5      = 1024 MB
iPhone 5S     = 1024 MB

iPod Touch 1G  =  128 MB
iPod Touch 2G  =  128 MB
iPod Touch 3G  =  256 MB
iPod Touch 4G  =  256 MB
iPod Touch 5G  =  512 MB

iPad           =  256 MB
iPad 2         =  512 MB
iPad (3)       = 1024 MB
iPad (4)       = 1024 MB
iPad Air       = 1024 MB

iPad mini (1G) =  512 MB
iPad mini (2G) = 1024 MB
```

Comment: Tony - there are multiple versions of the iPod Touch also - you should include those variations as well. Good summary!

Answer (score 58):

## iPhone

- iPhone (June 2007): 128MB
- iPhone 3G (July 2008): 128MB
- iPhone 3GS (June 2009): 256MB
- iPhone 4 (June 2010): 512MB
- iPhone 4S (October 2011): 512MB
- iPhone 5 (September 2012): 1GB
- iPhone 5S (September 2013): 1GB
- iPhone 6 (September 2014): 1GB
- iPhone 6 Plus (September 2014): 1GB
- iPhone 6S (September 2015): 2GB
- iPhone 6S Plus (September 2015): 2GB
- iPhone 7 (September 2016): 2GB
- iPhone 7 Plus (September 2016): 3GB

## iPod touch

- 1st generation (September 2007): 128MB
- 2nd generation (September 2008): 128MB
- 3rd generation (September 2009): 256MB
- 4th generation (September 2010): 256MB
- 5th generation (October 2012): 512MB
- 6th generation (July 2015): 1GB

## iPad

- 1st generation (April 2010): 256MB
- iPad 2 (2011): 512MB
- 3rd generation (March 2012): 1GB
- 4th generation (November 2012): 1GB
- iPad Air (November 2013): 1GB
- iPad Air 2 (October 2014): 2GB
- iPad Pro 12.9" (November 2015): 4GB
- iPad Pro 9.7" (April 2016): 2GB

## iPad mini

- 1st generation (November 2012): 512MB
- iPad mini 2 (November 2013): 1GB
- iPad mini 3 (October 2014): 1GB
- iPad mini 4 (September 2015): 2GB

## Apple Watch

- 1st generation (April 2015): 512MB

## Apple TV

- 2nd generation (2010): 256MB
- 3rd generation (2012): 512MB
- 4th generation (2015): 2GB

iOS doesn't use swap space, therefore, only RAM will be available to processes. (That said, iOS does support paging executables.)

Comment: You mean it doesn't support paging memory (to flash in this case). I'm sure that it supports virtual memory.

Comment: By virtual memory, I didn't mean virtual address space. In fact it does support paging too, but not paging to flash (i.e. no swap files).

Comment: There's no paging of data, but readonly pages (ie instruction data) will be freed and reloaded as needed.

Comment: Think of it as an OS X kernel without any swap files, it'll still page executables.

Comment: This is probably because unlike a harddrive flash memory can only be written to a limited number of times... before it fails. So this scheme vastly improves memory life.

Comment: iPod touch 4th generation: 256MB

Comment: This answer ignores a key part of the question "available for my Cocoa Application?". There is no fixed amount, and you cant reliably ask the device how much you're allowed to have. You need to use as little as possible, don't ask for more too quickly, and be prepared to handle low memory warnings.

Comment: @AnthonyLambert really nice analyse here

Answer (score 10):

iPhone and iPod touch has 128 megs of ram, but 3rd party applications should only count on having about 20 megs available.

Answer (score 6):

As Mehrdad Afshari says, it's 128Mb (except for the 3GS which has twice that), but why do you need to know? Not all of it is accessible to programs and the exact amount varies. Presumably activities like running iPod in the background saps some memory and OS2.1, for instance, seemed to leave less free memory than 2.0.

The key, application wise, is to cache stuff rather than require everything in memory and to heed the memory warning notifications. Your app will be forced to quit if you don't. (If it quits with status 101, you were using too much memory.)

Comment: because I am writing an application with an in memory database. I will write it in a different way depending on how much memory is available.

Answer (score 0):

Go to [ios app maximum memory budget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5887248/ios-app-maximum-memory-budget) to  see more devices and RAM amount that can be really allocated.