# Is there some memory limits in stack item in iOS?

Tags: ios

I want 1 MB sized `NSData` object with all bytes set to 255.

Method where I want to run this code crashes on `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`:

```
const size_t size = 1024 * 1024;
uint8_t bytes[size] = {[0 ...size - 1] = 255};
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:bytes length:size];
NSLog(@"%@", data);
```

Comment: Does this work with size = 1024?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2918691/is-there-stack-size-in-iphone

Comment: Okay. Should it be marked as duplicate or how can I accept your answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To close the question here is the answer.

[Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/CreatingThreads/CreatingThreads.html) says, that stack size is 1 MB for main thread in iOS.