# ios app maximum memory budget

Tags: iphone, ios, memory, memory-management

I'm working on an ios game that's targeting as a minimum the 3gs. We are using HD assets for retina display devices (iphone 4, ipod touch 4th gen).

Memory wise, Ipod Touch 4th gen seems to be the most constraint device for us since it has the same amount of RAM (256 compared to Iphone 4's 512) as 3gs but we're using HD assets on it. The app used to crash when trying to load 100-110mb of ram but now that we're down to 70MB, we've never had loading crash.

After lots of searching around, there seems to be no official hard limit so how should we go about knowing what memory budget to use to be safe?  We want to be able to give the artists a budget they can use without memory worries for each map.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS memory allocation - how much memory can be used in an application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6044147/ios-memory-allocation-how-much-memory-can-be-used-in-an-application)

Comment: Not sure how this question can be a duplicate of something which was asked at a later point of time.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I think you've answered your own question: try not to go beyond the 70 Mb limit, however it really depends on many things: what iOS version you're using (not SDK), how many applications running in background, what exact memory you're using etc.

Just avoid the instant memory splashes (e.g. you're using 40 Mb of RAM, and then allocating 80 Mb's more for some short computation). In this case iOS would kill your application immediately.

You should also consider lazy loading of assets (load them only when you really need and not beforehand).

Comment: It's just that we wanted to put as much stuff as we could (graphics & sounds). Artists will always want to put as much as they possibly can into a game that's why I want to limit them with a budget. I guess we'll just have to test on many different devices in different settings to find a reasonable maximum memory footprint to use.

Comment: Will allocating only 70MB (which is presumably under the budget) at *any* time on that device (even after heavy usage in other memory-hungry apps) always guarantee a successful allocation, or will it potentially still crash?

Comment: @Steven Lu it depends on your device. E.g. on newer ones, like iPhone5 or iPad4 70 Mb allocation is not a problem at all.

Comment: yes but i want to know if I can be sure that as long as I keep my app's total usage under the magical device specific memory budget that it will not get terminated!

Comment: there are no guarantees

Answer (score 480):

Results of testing with the utility Split wrote (link is in his answer):

**device: (crash amount/total amount/percentage of total)**

- iPad1: 127MB/256MB/49%
- iPad2: 275MB/512MB/53%
- iPad3: 645MB/1024MB/62%
- iPad4: 585MB/1024MB/57%  (iOS 8.1)
- iPad Mini 1st Generation: 297MB/512MB/58%
- iPad Mini retina: 696MB/1024MB/68% (iOS 7.1)
- iPad Air: 697MB/1024MB/68%
- iPad Air 2: 1383MB/2048MB/68% (iOS 10.2.1)
- iPad Pro 9.7": 1395MB/1971MB/71% (iOS 10.0.2 (14A456))
- iPad Pro 10.5”: 3057/4000/76% (iOS 11 beta4)
- iPad Pro 12.9” (2015): 3058/3999/76% (iOS 11.2.1)
- iPad Pro 12.9” (2017): 3057/3974/77% (iOS 11 beta4)
- iPad Pro 11.0” (2018): 2858/3769/76% (iOS 12.1)
- iPad Pro 12.9” (2018, 1TB): 4598/5650/81% (iOS 12.1)
- iPad 10.2: 1844/2998/62% (iOS 13.2.3)
- iPod touch 4th gen: 130MB/256MB/51% (iOS 6.1.1)
- iPod touch 5th gen: 286MB/512MB/56% (iOS 7.0)
- iPhone4: 325MB/512MB/63%
- iPhone4s: 286MB/512MB/56%
- iPhone5: 645MB/1024MB/62%
- iPhone5s: 646MB/1024MB/63%
- iPhone6: 645MB/1024MB/62% (iOS 8.x)
- iPhone6+: 645MB/1024MB/62% (iOS 8.x)
- iPhone6s: 1396MB/2048MB/68% (iOS 9.2)
- iPhone6s+: 1392MB/2048MB/68% (iOS 10.2.1)
- iPhoneSE: 1395MB/2048MB/69% (iOS 9.3)
- iPhone7: 1395/2048MB/68% (iOS 10.2)
- iPhone7+: 2040MB/3072MB/66% (iOS 10.2.1)
- iPhone8: 1364/1990MB/70% (iOS 12.1)
- iPhone X: 1392/2785/50% (iOS 11.2.1)
- iPhone XS: 2040/3754/54% (iOS 12.1)
- iPhone XS Max: 2039/3735/55% (iOS 12.1)
- iPhone XR: 1792/2813/63% (iOS 12.1)
- iPhone 11: 2068/3844/54% (iOS 13.1.3)
- iPhone 11 Pro Max: 2067/3740/55% (iOS 13.2.3)
- iPhone 12 Pro: 3054/5703/54% (iOS 16.1)

Comment: iPhone4: similar value confirmed, seems legit :P

Comment: By the way, this app is also VERY useful to test state restoration in a real device, because it causes other apps to be freed from memory.

Comment: iPhone 5 crashes at ±645 MB.

Comment: iPhone 5S crashes at ±646 MB pretty reliably here.

Comment: There is an iPad 3rd generation and an iPad 4th generation. iPad3 refers to the 3rd generation I assume? If so, what are 4th generation specs? (See http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT5452 for device types.)

Comment: I don't have an iPad 4th generation available for testing. If you find out, let me know and I'll add it to the list.

Comment: @JasperPol I've edited your post to include various devices I have, I hope that's okay. I've added the iOS version I tested on in case it matters, but feel free to remove it if you think it's not important.

Comment: iPhone 4S crashes at ±286MB (286MB/512MB/56%).

Comment: iPhone 4S doesn't crash until it reaches ±363 MB for me. (iOS 5.1.1)

Comment: Awesome that this list has been created and maintained. In my experience, I've had to keep memory much lower to be safe, maybe 20% of what's shown here. Device-to-device differences are also highly variable.

Comment: Just ran this on a 12.9 iPad Pro. Memory warning at 2451MB, crash at 3064MB, total 3981MB.

Comment: iPhone 6s+: 1392MB/2048MB/ 68% (iOS 10.2.1); iPhone 7+: 2040MB/3072MB/66% (iOS 10.2.1)

Comment: I retested iPad Air 2, because current values on list looks suspiciously (only 58% on 2GB device). And indeed my result is similar to other 2gb devices:
iPad Air 2: 1383MB/2048MB/68% (iOS 10.2.1)

Comment: And the result for the last missing device:
iPhone 7: 1395/2048MB/68% (iOS 10.2)

Comment: sO You have all these ios devices on standby or you use simulator??

Comment: @bakalolo its not possible to use simulator to test, as it would use your mac it's ram

Comment: @Jasper: Please add 2 new devices:
iPad Pro 10.5”: 3057/4000/76% (iOS 11 beta4)
iPad Pro 12.9” (2017): 3057/3974/77% (iOS 11 beta4)

Comment: The amount is a resident size (RAM) used by my app or does the GPU resources are counted too?

Comment: @zoujyjs GPU is not taken into account.

Comment: @Jasper: I tested 2 more devices:

iPhone X: 1392/2785/50% (iOS 11.2.1) !!! ;

iPad Pro 12.9” (2015): 3058/3999/76% (iOS 11.2.1) ;

The important thing is iPhone X crashes at only 1392MB, which is only 50% of total memory. I tested it 2 times to make sure. 2nd time was just after killing all apps and rebooting. Results were the same.

Comment: @Jasper No, in my case (a game app) GPU resources is accounted.

Comment: @zoujyjs I'm not sure, you'll have to check as I'm a bit out of the development world.. What I meant is that I don't think the tool Split wrote is taking GPU into account

Comment: I have just made tests on iOS 12 - iPhone X and iPad Pro 12.9” (2017). Results are very similar to iOS 11.

Comment: @Jasper Data for new devices from 2018:
iPhone XS Max: 2039/3735/55% (iOS 12.1);
iPad Pro 11.0” 256GB (2018): 2858/3769/76% (iOS 12.1);
iPad Pro 12.9” 1TB (2018):  4598/5650/81% (iOS 12.1);

Comment: @Jasper Two more results: iPhone8: 1364/1990MB/70% (iOS 12.1)
iPhone XS: 2040/3754/54% (iOS 12.1)
Jasper you can change device name from 'iPad Pro 12.9” (2018)' to 'iPad Pro 12.9” (2018, 1TB)'. This is important because only 1TB version has 6GB Ram, others have 4GB.
Anybody with iPhone XR or iPad 12.9 (2018, 4GB)?

Comment: @Slyv, here you go for iPhone XR: 1792/2813/63% (iOS 12.1)

Comment: @Jasper Could you update the list with few recent comments (iPhone XR, iPhone 8, iPhone XS)?

Comment: @Jasper Here are reports from 3 more devices: iPhone 11 Pro Max: 2067/3740/55% (iOS 13.2.3);
iPhone 11: 2068/3844/54% (iOS 13.1.3);
iPad 10.2: 1844/2998/62% (iOS 13.2.3);
Please update the list

Comment: iPhone 11 (4GB) and iPhone XR (3GB) crash at 1.8g~2g ,  iPhone X (3GB) and iPhone 8 (2GB) crash at ~1.4g...seems apple reserved about 1GB memory for these devices with dual or more cameras

Comment: Xcode 14.1 shows memory limit in Debug Navigator Memory graph when memory usage approaches it.

Answer (score 145):

I created small utility which tries to allocate as much memory as possible to crash and it records when memory warnings and crash happened. This helps to find out what's the memory budget for any iOS device.

https://github.com/Split82/iOSMemoryBudgetTest

Comment: I made an interesting test: ran my app with xcode monitoring memory usage, entered background, ran the BudgetTest. The test was killed while my in-background app wasn't. I'm interested in knowing why. Also, this goes against what @cprcrack said in the other answer.

Answer (score 21):

In my app, user experience is better if more memory is used, so I have to decide if I really should free *all* the memory I can in `didReceiveMemoryWarning`. Based on Split's and Jasper Pol's answer, using a maximum of 45% of the total device memory appears to be a safe threshold (thanks guys).

In case someone wants to look at my actual implementation:

```
#import "mach/mach.h"

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Remember to call super
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // If we are using more than 45% of the memory, free even important resources,
    // because the app might be killed by the OS if we don't
    if ([self __getMemoryUsedPer1] > 0.45)
    {
        // Free important resources here
    }

    // Free regular unimportant resources always here
}

- (float)__getMemoryUsedPer1
{
    struct mach_task_basic_info info;
    mach_msg_type_number_t size = sizeof(info);
    kern_return_t kerr = task_info(mach_task_self(), MACH_TASK_BASIC_INFO, (task_info_t)&info, &size);
    if (kerr == KERN_SUCCESS)
    {
        float used_bytes = info.resident_size;
        float total_bytes = [NSProcessInfo processInfo].physicalMemory;
        //NSLog(@"Used: %f MB out of %f MB (%f%%)", used_bytes / 1024.0f / 1024.0f, total_bytes / 1024.0f / 1024.0f, used_bytes * 100.0f / total_bytes);
        return used_bytes / total_bytes;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Swift (based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27559770/423171)):

```
func __getMemoryUsedPer1() -> Float
{
    let MACH_TASK_BASIC_INFO_COUNT = (sizeof(mach_task_basic_info_data_t) / sizeof(natural_t))
    let name = mach_task_self_
    let flavor = task_flavor_t(MACH_TASK_BASIC_INFO)
    var size = mach_msg_type_number_t(MACH_TASK_BASIC_INFO_COUNT)
    var infoPointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<mach_task_basic_info>.alloc(1)
    let kerr = task_info(name, flavor, UnsafeMutablePointer(infoPointer), &size)
    let info = infoPointer.move()
    infoPointer.dealloc(1)
    if kerr == KERN_SUCCESS
    {
        var used_bytes: Float = Float(info.resident_size)
        var total_bytes: Float = Float(NSProcessInfo.processInfo().physicalMemory)
        println("Used: \(used_bytes / 1024.0 / 1024.0) MB out of \(total_bytes / 1024.0 / 1024.0) MB (\(used_bytes * 100.0 / total_bytes)%%)")
        return used_bytes / total_bytes
    }
    return 1
}
```

Comment: size should be TASK_BASIC_INFO_COUNT instead of sizeof(info) - this mistake copy-pasted to many places with same code

Comment: Thanks Speakus. You seem to be right based on [this link](http://www.gnu.org/software/hurd/gnumach-doc/Task-Information.html). Do you have any other reference where this information can be found?

Comment: apple uses TASK_BASIC_INFO_COUNT [too](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-1699.22.73/bsd/kern/vm_pressure.c)

Comment: 45% is not safe limit anymore, it is too close to 50% crash value for iPhone X. I suggest using 40%, or separate value for each device.

Answer (score 9):

By forking SPLITS repo, I built one to test iOS memory that can be allocated to the Today's Extension

[iOSMemoryBudgetTestForExtension](https://github.com/harsh62/iOSMemoryBudgetTestForExtension)

Following is the result that i got in iPhone 5s

**Memory Warning at 10 MB**

**App Crashed at 12 MB**

*By this means Apple is merely allowing any extensions to work with their full potential*.

Answer (score 8):

You should watch session 147 from the [WWDC 2010 Session videos](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/). It is "Advanced Performance Optimization on iPhone OS, part 2".
There is a lot of good advice on memory optimizations.

Some of the tips are:

- Use nested `NSAutoReleasePool`s to make sure your memory usage does not spike.
- Use `CGImageSource` when creating thumbnails from large images.
- Respond to low memory warnings.

Comment: My question is not about how to optimize (thanks for the link though), it's about how much can we allow ourselves to use. The reason is that for example, if we optimize to gain 20mb, then artists will want to use that 20mb if it's within the reasonable "budget", aka sure that it won't cause any performance issues or memory crash.

Comment: OK. The crash will be because the OS is terminating the app because of constrained memory. You could just add an `NSLog` inside `didReceiveMemoryWarning` and then do some testing where you allocate different amounts of memory and then see when the memory warnings start to kick in.

Answer (score 8):

Starting with iOS13, there is an Apple-supported way of querying this by using

```
#include <os/proc.h>

size_t os_proc_available_memory(void)
```

Introduced here:
https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/606/

Around min 29-ish.

Edit: 
Adding link to documentation
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/os/3191911-os_proc_available_memory?language=objc

Comment: Finally! I tested os_proc_available_memory() on few devices, and results are very similar to the values i the big table above!

Answer (score 4):

I created one more list by sorting Jaspers list by device RAM (I made my own tests with Split's tool and fixed some results - check my comments in Jaspers thread).

**device RAM: percent range to crash**

- 256MB: 49% - 51%
- 512MB: 53% - 63%
- 1024MB: 57% - 68%
- 2048MB: 68% - 69%
- 3072MB: 63% - 66%
- 4096MB: 77%
- 6144MB: 81%

Special cases:

- iPhone X (3072MB): 50%
- iPhone XS/XS Max (4096MB): 55%
- iPhone XR (3072MB): 63%
- iPhone 11/11 Pro Max (4096MB): 54% - 55%

Device RAM can be read easily:

```
[NSProcessInfo processInfo].physicalMemory
```

From my experience it is safe to use 45% for 1GB devices, 50% for 2/3GB devices and 55% for 4GB devices. Percent for macOS can be a bit bigger.

Comment: update: It seems iPhone X is an exception - it crashes when 50% of RAM is used (tested with iOSMemoryBudgetTest app). I updated the list.

Answer (score 3):

```
- (float)__getMemoryUsedPer1
{
    struct mach_task_basic_info info;
    mach_msg_type_number_t size = MACH_TASK_BASIC_INFO;
    kern_return_t kerr = task_info(mach_task_self(), MACH_TASK_BASIC_INFO, (task_info_t)&info, &size);
    if (kerr == KERN_SUCCESS)
    {
        float used_bytes = info.resident_size;
        float total_bytes = [NSProcessInfo processInfo].physicalMemory;
        //NSLog(@"Used: %f MB out of %f MB (%f%%)", used_bytes / 1024.0f / 1024.0f, total_bytes / 1024.0f / 1024.0f, used_bytes * 100.0f / total_bytes);
        return used_bytes / total_bytes;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

If one will use TASK_BASIC_INFO_COUNT instead of MACH_TASK_BASIC_INFO, you will get

kerr == KERN_INVALID_ARGUMENT (4)

Comment: You should at least mention that your answer is almost an exact copy & paste of **@cprcrack's** above. The only difference is TASK_BASIC_INFO_COUNT.

Answer (score 1):

Working with the many answers above, I have implemented Apples new method `os_proc_available_memory()` for iOS 13+ coupled with `NSByteCountFormatter` which offers a number of useful formatting options for nicer output of the memory:

```c
#include <os/proc.h>

....

- (NSString *)memoryStringForBytes:(unsigned long long)memoryBytes {
    NSByteCountFormatter *byteFormatter = [[NSByteCountFormatter alloc] init];
    byteFormatter.allowedUnits = NSByteCountFormatterUseGB;
    byteFormatter.countStyle = NSByteCountFormatterCountStyleMemory;
    NSString *memoryString = [byteFormatter stringFromByteCount:memoryBytes];
    return memoryString;
}

- (void)memoryLoggingOutput {
    if (@available(iOS 13.0, *)) {
        NSLog(@"Physical memory available: %@", [self memoryStringForBytes:[NSProcessInfo processInfo].physicalMemory]);
        NSLog(@"Memory A (brackets): %@", [self memoryStringForBytes:(long)os_proc_available_memory()]);
        NSLog(@"Memory B (no brackets): %@", [self memoryStringForBytes:(long)os_proc_available_memory]);
    }
}
```

Important note: **Do not forget the `()` at the end.** I have included both `NSLog` options in in the `memoryLoggingOutput` method because it does not warn you that they are missing and failure to include the brackets returns an unexpected yet constant result.

The string returned from the method `memoryStringForBytes` outputs values like so:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [self memoryStringForBytes:(long)os_proc_available_memory()]); // 1.93 GB
// 2 seconds later
NSLog(@"%@", [self memoryStringForBytes:(long)os_proc_available_memory()]); // 1.84 GB
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not only about memory % usage, but also about memory fragmentation.
If your app allocates and deallocates big chunks mixed with smaller chunks it might be, that big chunks wont fit into the reserved memory for the app and your app will get "jetsammed" even if you havent used a lot of your memory (e.g. at 35% of the total amount)

If that is the case, you should consider using memory pools and reuse of objects. Also a heavy use of String-Operations might be bad for your memory food print.