# Ios run time memory limitation

Tags: ios, memory

I know this has been asked a lot of times, but what people saying is not accurate according to my experience. I had an app which will use up over 30 MB on a device, and it can still run an iPhone 3g without much problem. So I am wondering if there is a fairly accurate answer about how much memory can an app use for iPhone 3g, 3gs and 4. I've read a lot of people saying 20, 40 and 120MB accordingly. But I think that's not the true limit.

Thank you in advance for any reply!

Comment: In the end the answer is "it depends." It depends what else the user is running on the device, doing with the device.

Comment: Note that the earlier reported values may have changed with OS versions. I know for a fact that 30 MB (as seen in Memory Monitor) used to be a hard ceiling for applications running on the iPhone 3G, no matter the other conditions, but that may have changed in iOS 4.x.

Answer (score 1):

There is no set number.  The limit is based on the OS's judgement of its current state.  If it feels that your application is starting to hog memory then it will start sending warnings and eventually terminate it.  This will happen especially quickly if your app spikes in memory usage (i.e. makes a lot of allocations in a short period of time).  There is a bit more information in this question:  [ios app maximum memory budget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5887248/ios-app-maximum-memory-budget)