# How to get memory usage in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I need to get the memory usage (MB) for my app programmatically in Swift. I found sample code for Objective-C. Anyone can help me to convert this into Swift. Thanks!

```
void report_memory(void) {
  struct task_basic_info info;
  mach_msg_type_number_t size = sizeof(info);
  kern_return_t kerr = task_info(mach_task_self(),
                             TASK_BASIC_INFO,
                             (task_info_t)&info,
                             &size);
  if( kerr == KERN_SUCCESS ) {
    NSLog(@"Memory in use (in bytes): %u", info.resident_size);
  } else {
    NSLog(@"Error with task_info(): %s", mach_error_string(kerr));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 13):

edit: oops, should have checked for duplicates first, Nate answered this question already [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27556807/swift-pointer-problems-with-mach-task-basic-info).  Though you might want to note the slight difference in my version, which uses `withUnsafeMutablePointer`.

You’re getting downvoted since people don’t like “How can I convert this Obj-C code to Swift” questions, however in this case it might be fair enough since this this specific conversion is particularly hairy.  I think this is working:

```
func report_memory() {
    var info = task_basic_info()
    var count = mach_msg_type_number_t(sizeofValue(info))/4

    let kerr: kern_return_t = withUnsafeMutablePointer(&info) {

        task_info(mach_task_self_,
            task_flavor_t(TASK_BASIC_INFO),
            task_info_t($0),
            &count)

    }

    if kerr == KERN_SUCCESS {
        println("Memory in use (in bytes): \(info.resident_size)")
    }
    else {
        println("Error with task_info(): " +
            (String.fromCString(mach_error_string(kerr)) ?? "unknown error"))
    }
}
```

There’s a couple of basic coercions – `sizeof` returns an `Int`, but the function call needs a `UInt32`.  Similarly (and slightly more infuriatingly), `TASK_BASIC_INFO` is an `Int32`, but the call needs a `UInt32`.

The nasty part is passing in the third parameter.  `task_info` takes a pointer to multiple different kinds of structs of different sizes depending on what kind of info you want.  So you need to get a pointer from your `task_basic_info` object, then cast it to the specific kind of pointer `task_info` actually wants (which is, once you wade through all the typedefs, a pointer to `UInt32`).

The docs for `task_info` say that the last `count` parameter is supposed to be a count of the “maximum number of integers in task_info” but when it says integers I guess it means 32-bit integers hence divide by 4.

Comment: Hey! Did you figured out, how to find the limit before the app start sending memory warning? in other words, how can i know when i'm "pushing" the app memory usage, and i stop do what ever process i'm doing?

Comment: In Swift 3, I now get `'init' is unavailable: use 'withMemoryRebound(to:capacity:_)' to temporarily view memory as another layout-compatible type.`

Comment: Swift 3 solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39048651/650558

Comment: This is memory usage by App(process) not device.

Comment: Outdated. Gives a handful of compiler errors in Swift 5.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found a solution. Please see below code snippet.

```
func report_memory() {
    // constant
    let MACH_TASK_BASIC_INFO_COUNT = (sizeof(mach_task_basic_info_data_t) / sizeof(natural_t))

    // prepare parameters
    let name   = mach_task_self_
    let flavor = task_flavor_t(MACH_TASK_BASIC_INFO)
    var size   = mach_msg_type_number_t(MACH_TASK_BASIC_INFO_COUNT)

    // allocate pointer to mach_task_basic_info
    var infoPointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<mach_task_basic_info>.alloc(1)

    // call task_info - note extra UnsafeMutablePointer(...) call
    let kerr = task_info(name, flavor, UnsafeMutablePointer(infoPointer), &size)

    // get mach_task_basic_info struct out of pointer
    let info = infoPointer.move()

    // deallocate pointer
    infoPointer.dealloc(1)

    // check return value for success / failure
    if kerr == KERN_SUCCESS {
        println("Memory in use (in MB): \(info.resident_size/1000000)")
    } else {
        let errorString = String(CString: mach_error_string(kerr), encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding)
        println(errorString ?? "Error: couldn't parse error string")
    }    
}
```

Comment: Copying someone else's answer, is not equal to "found a solution" At least give a credit to a person who first posted it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27559770/5318223