# Programmatically get memory usage iOS

Tags: ios, memory

This question is in regards to an already answered post.

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787160/programmatically-retrieve-memory-usage-on-iphone#*=*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787160/programmatically-retrieve-memory-usage-on-iphone#_=_)

So i see that you can grab the number of pages that the kernel has allocated an any given point using info.residentPages.

Now why is this number different from the number that Xcode GUI gives me (In the debug navigator under Memory tab you get a nice dashboard with the number of MB in current use.)? Should'nt this be the same as what (info.residentPages >> 20) would give me?

Comment: Is this what you´re looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29794281/how-to-get-memory-usage-in-swift

Comment: No thats literally what i posted in my question. That was just an example on how to convert what i posted to swift. Check the link i posted.