# In which cases "MTLDevice newTextureWithDescriptor" can fail in iOS?

Tags: ios, memory-management, gpu, metal

In my iOS project `Metal` is used extensively.
Sometimes `MTLDevice newTextureWithDescriptor` fails to create a texture.
Texture format is valid, it's a small RGBA 512x512 texture, everything is set up correctly.

When I print `MTLDevice.currentAllocatedSize >> 20` it's `1396 MB` on `iPhone XR` ( `A12` processor ).

I've used a lot *this thread for max runtime RAM estimate*: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15200855/2567725 
So I believe for iPhone XR max allowed RAM is `1792 MB`.

I guess the texture is not created because RAM has been exsausted.

So the guestions are:

1. Is it true that on A12 Metal's `currentAllocatedSize` correlates with `CPU` memory, and `GPU` memory is "shared" with the CPU one, so `1792 MB = GPU+CPU` for iPhone XR ?
2. Is there any way to get the description of Metal error? (now it just returns `nil` in `newTextureWithDescriptor`).
3. Is it possible to know how Metal allocation strategy works, e.g. how small available `RAM` should be to `MTLDevice newTextureWithDescriptor` return `nil` ?

**UPDATE**: 
In some cases, however, `MTLDevice.currentAllocatedSize >> 20` is much less, e.g. `14 MB`, so I suspect `Metal` has some state corruption. But how to check what's the reason of the error?

The debug description of a texture descriptor:

```
textureDescriptor.pixelFormat = 70
textureDescriptor.width = 512
textureDescriptor.height = 512
textureDescriptor.textureType = 3
textureDescriptor.usage = 23
textureDescriptor.arrayLength = 1000
textureDescriptor.sampleCount = 1
textureDescriptor.mipmapLevelCount = 1
device.currentAllocatedSize >> 20 = 14
```

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: @0xBFE1A8 I can't post the code of entire class, but here I've used an identical approach: https://github.com/gatamar/HowCoreImageInteractsWithMetal/blob/master/HowCoreImageInteractsWithMetal/ViewController.mm

Please look at `- (MTLTextureDescriptor*)createTextureDescriptor` and `id<MTLTexture> metalTexture = [_metalDevice newTextureWithDescriptor:_metalTextureDescriptor];` - everything is very similar in the real project.

Comment: Regarding 1: on iOS you deal with a unified memory model, hence the memory is shared between CPU and GPU. See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/shader_authoring/developing_and_debugging_metal_shaders?language=objc