# Core data storage limit, Cache Limit, RAM limit on iphone

Tags: ios, image, caching, core-data

I am making a some complex app, in which every detail is imp. i have some questions
1. how much storage limit we have, if we plan to save big files on core data/cache.
2. Whats the RAM limit on iphone? Actually searching for some table that can give detailed info about IOS devices on this. Because i need to handle memory warnings and defend App crashes. 
3. Its better to save images in cache or core data, assume you have a lot of images approx. 200-250.

Thanks

Comment: try to not store the images inside the CoreData, because it can make the CoreData slow. you should the images in the filesystem, and save the name/path of the image only (or whatever you need to fined the proper image), and load the images from there.

Comment: The app's RAM limit depends on how many apps are running and other factors. In general, your app should be less than 10megs in ram and you will likely not run into problems with your app getting killed. Both iPhone and iPad have an upper limit of 700 megs of memory mapped file IO space (not the same as ram). Disk space depends on how big the storage on the device is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) I am not aware of any storage limit. Obviously, you will never get 64GB or more - since no device is larger ;-). My wife's facebook app consumes >5GB at the moment... I suppose they did something wrong. The only important point is to fail gracefully (show a dialog, clean some space, ...) if the storage is full.

2) The RAM limit varies depending on the iPhone model and the currently running applications. Also there are some iPods with less memory in market. 30MB should be pretty safe. Total physical memory of the device can be retrieved as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8032635/responding-to-ram-availability-in-ios/8072278#8072278) while retrival of the available RAM can be derived from [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11427761/total-ram-in-iphone) question.

3) Maybe [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdPerformance.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003468-SW5) is a good starting point. I would always write image data to the file system and just store the file name inside the database, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4158286/storing-images-in-core-data).

Comment: So as per my experience agreed to both @ chris and @holex. thnks so much, file system is a better call . Also, is there a limit of caching  per ios devices because, i found some issue in one app in which caching was done in NSDocumentDir... i think NSCachinDir should be used (pls reply on this) ...and is there any limit of caching/ precaution we need to follow for smooth app on this side.

Comment: @christoph....bt yes...we should store images which change very often in NSCacheDirectory and not in NSDocumentDirectory RIGHT ???

Comment: Without knowing your use case in detail: yes. Maybe [this](http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/data-management/local-file-storage-in-ios-5) could help you.